Python - Moving object on local axis
I am trying to make an object move around a bit randomly at constant speed in blender on the x and y axis using blender scripting. I have thought about various solutions, and I decided to go with rotating the object randomly and then moving it forward on the local axis, becuase then it will also face towards the moving direction, which I want. I am not sure how to achieve this though. I have the code below. What it does is rotate the object randomly and then keyframe that rotation at an interval of one second. Since the object rotates slightly on each frame it may be best to move the object slightly on each frame, and keyframe every frame, as well so it always moving in the exact direction its facing. How can I achieve this?
for i in range (1,number_of_seconds):
    new_obj2.rotation_euler = [0, 0, math.radians(random.uniform(0, 90))]
    #Move forward on local axis
    new_obj2.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=i*24)
    new_obj2.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=i*24)


new_obj2.location += new_obj2.matrix_world @ mathutils.Vector((1, 0, 0)) ?
